# How to calculate the center of an n-cube (hypercube) given the minimum values and maximum values in each dimension?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

I am working with a box-embedding-based method in machine learning, and for a particular problem, I have two objects that are represented as two $n$-cubes in $n$-dimension ($n$ might be $16, 32, 64, ...,$ so the method should be general for an arbitrary $n$). Now I need to compute some heuristics distance between these cubes. Currently, I have the minimum and maximum values on each dimension of each cube. I think that one possible start for me is to calculate the distance between the centers of the cubes. However, I am not sure what the way to proceed is, as I found no reference for calculating the centers of the cubes.

Comment: Think on the case $n=2$.

Comment: I know how to find the center with $n = 2$ by finding the average on both direction, I'm just not sure if that can be generalized to $n>2$ since I cannot find any source confirming that. Can it be generalized to $n>2$?

Comment: Yes, it can be generalized

Answer (score 0):

As @jjagmath replied, we can think about finding the center in the case of $n = 2$ by finding the average of the coordinates in the two dimensions. Then we use the same idea for higher dimensions.